# Is it possible to send FFMPEG output to a php file?

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

I want to send ffmpeg output to a php file so I can use a regex and update the output into a database. This will allow me to handle progress for multiple uploads. Does anyone know how to do this? **Can it be done?** Currently I can execute a php file with parameters after the ffmpeg command, and get ffmpeg to write to a txt file but can I send the output to the php file and execute it?

**execute php file with parameters**

```
&& php /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site/update_db.php ".$parameter1." ".$parameter2.";
```

**Write output to txt file**

```
ffmpeg command and filepath to converted  1> /home/g/Desktop/output.txt 2>&1
```

**Can something like this be done?**

```
ffmpeg command and filepath to converted   1> php /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/site/update_db.php ".$output." 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can read STDIN.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

If it were me, I'd just execute FFMPEG from within PHP.  You have a bit more flexibility that way, but I know that isn't desirable for every application.

Comment: I am executing ffmpeg in php with exec. I tried $file = file_get_contents("php://stdin", "r");
    echo $file;
after I executed cli command and got nothing

Comment: @Scarface, of course not, PHP's STDIN is for when you execute PHP.  If you want to get the output from `exec()`, you simply need to reed what it returns.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: of course but I need output on a constant basis. So if I tell ffmpeg to write to text file, that file is constantly updated as the process works, I checked. How then can you keep getting output from cli to a php file and then have that file executed? So then is this still possible?

Comment: @Scarface, in that case, you need to use `proc_open()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: It says that it writes to a file. But how do you send the results to a php file that can be retrieved in the file and processed through a variable? I am a little confused what proc_open does...I would really appreciate it if you could show me a brief example of how to use the function to achieve my purpose. Also, this could work with multiple processes being executed right (it would produce a unique instance on each execution to be sent to a file)?

Comment: Here is a `proc_open()` tutorial/example:  http://www.molecularsciences.org/PHP/proc_open_tutorial_and_examples

Comment: Hey Brad I have been trying to read up on proc_open and I am kinda going crazy now. I understand the way it works in terms of stdout now but how can you make it send data and execute a php file? The demo when executed just returns data to the browser and writes data to a file if there is an error. I need the ability to have ffmpeg send constant information for each file conversion...

Comment: I would be so grateful if you could point me in the right direction here. Is this the right solutution for creating a php mysql ffmpeg progress bar?

Comment: @Scarface, you don't need to send data to execute a PHP file... you are executing FFMPEG from your PHP script, right?  Then all you have to do is read/parse the output from the pipes available to you when you run proc_open.

Comment: I have been fiddling with that. How do you do that haha? There is no documentation on how to read and parse output. Only on how to throw it in text file.

Comment: @Scarface, the tutorial I linked to shows you how to do just that!  If it is still giving you trouble, you should start a second post with the question simply being, "How can I read live output from a program stated with proc_open()".

Comment: I did and noone responded. The tutorial you sent me definitely does not show me how to do what I want to do because when I execute proc_open, if I change the output to 2 => array("pipe","w") and echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]); The output only echoes at the end when the process is done. I really don't think this function can do what I am trying to do. I need to have the output updated every 10 seconds so I don't know if you have to send to a php file or if output can be parsed in the current file as it comes. I wish you would give me some guidance here. I have been googling for hours.

Comment: ... I have no idea what more guidance I could possibly give you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to call ffmpeg, then use the content of the output parameter to get returned output.

But doing so only allow you to get the output once the program execution is terminated:

> If a program is started with this
>   function, in order for it to continue
>   running in the background, the output
>   of the program must be redirected to a
>   file or another output stream. Failing
>   to do so will cause PHP to hang until
>   the execution of the program ends.

Comment: How does that look? I am already using php exec to execute ffmpeg.

Comment: Plus I would need to be able to update progress every 10 seconds. I can't keep refreshing exec.

Comment: Could you maybe do an example because I really do not understand what you are trying to tell me. You are saying you can redirect output of ffmpeg to a file or output stream right? So is it possible to redirect that output to a php file where that file is executed and the output can be processed? I am trying to update on a reoccurring basis for a progress bar.